# Restricting Apache VirtualHosts to their own directory

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, .htaccess

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, and I have configured it to accept connections from several domains. The sites are all stored in `/var/www/html` like so:

```
example.com
sub.example.com
sample.com
...
```

Some of these sites are a work-in-progress, and I have created user accounts for the people working on these sites. For such sites, I did a `mount --bind` of the site's folder to the user's home folder, which they are chrooted to. So, if a user `john` was working on `sample.com`, they would see the folder as `/sample.com` when they log in.

Clearly, the idea is to restrict the users to the projects that they are in charge of. However, because PHP is run with `www-data`, which owns `/var/www/html`, any user can modify any file in `/var/www/html` using PHP.

Is there any way, through `.htaccess` or any other way, to lock the PHP in each of the site's folders such that it is allowed to only modify folders inside of its site folder? I.E. If I am running a PHP script inside `sample.com`, the script shouldn't be able to read or write folders above `sample.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bindfs` instead.
Put all your code under `/var/www/html/<project>`, `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html` and use `bindfs` to mount it in the users directory.
Examples:

```
bindfs -g www-data -m chroot_user1 --create-for-user=www-data --create-for-group=www-data --create-with-perms=0644,a+X /var/www/html/example.com/ /home/chroot_user1/wwwroot_example.com/
```

Chroot users will see the code as themselves as owner.
But the real permissions will be www-data under the apache directory.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Carl. Couldn't the user still use the `exec()` command in PHP to run shell scripts as `www-data` though?

Comment: They will run php script under there username, but writes to the directory will result in www-data in the apache directory

Comment: Sounds like a fantastic command. Thanks @Carl!